# What can be the best UX for too many forms

Tags: forms, long-forms

The web platform belongs to hotel industry and this page has too many form while adding guests at a time. Adding one by one form steps is also adding too many clicks so can anyone suggest the best UX for the same?

[image]

Comment: Hello Kaushal, Welcome to SE. Can you bring some example of entry titles? what is the type of them?

Comment: Sure @KeivanSina I will get it and update the screenshot.

Comment: What kind of information goes into those forms? Why is it necessary to have multiple forms + multiple submit buttons in the same screen?

Answer (score 2):

*It's hard to tell what's going on with your generic example, but I'll venture a guess …*

### Who is the target user?

Is this question for staff or guests?
For guests, you want to be very cautious about excessive density in the UI.
For staff, you want to be sure they are efficient with repetitive tasks.
Those two scenarios will result in very different UIs.

### Operational use case

Let's assume a hotel staff member is inputing data so that everything is ready when the guests arrive.

You mentioned these forms are all about inputing multiple guests in one go.
The norm for the hospitality industry is two guests per stay.
How can you help the user reach maximum efficiency in the most common scenario so they realize the biggest possible gain?

How about a simple form that has
the basic required fields for two guests,
one submit / save button,
and a single button to add more guests?

For bonus points, that "add more" button could include a count so the user could specify exactly how many more guests will be entered.

### Guest use case

I won't go into detail here; just imagine iterating on the operational perspective.

What's the most common scenario for guests?
How can you make them fell very welcomed and capable in that scenario?

### Iterate to find the unknowns

I'm a big believer in prototype-first product development. I start with a prototype designed for the most common scenario(s) and expand from there. Test that solution with real users and see what exceptions *they* find. You'll move to successful solutions much faster this way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you introduce a progress indicator (sometimes referred to as a wizard).

According to your example your progress indicator will consist of 10 steps - which is quite a lot - consider regrouping content for fewer steps. It's important for this component to give an overview, as well as indicate where in the process the user currently finds themself. Also consider whether users should be able to skip some steps, jump around or complete the entire form in a chronological order.

If introducing a progress indicator is too radical change, perhaps refine your current layout and remove unnecessary actions - like replacing the frequent "Update" button with only one "Save" button at the end of the entire form.